# How to transform infrared beam into visible range?

Tags: visible-light

I am looking for an easy method of turning an infrared beam into a visible beam.
There are some well-known ways to do it, for example a camera objective, but it that is very big and uncomfortable to use. I need a small thing for putting on glasses.

If you know of a material which can do this, that would be best, but an optical device is suitable too. There is only one requirement, it must be possible to make and use at home.

Comment: I don't think a "camera objective" is or does what you think it does.  Do you want to produce a visible image, or do you really want to upconvert the wavelength?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you often cannot see a beam even at visible wavelengths. For you to see something, light has to enter your eye. If a beam is not pointed at your eye, this usually doesn't happen. If it is pointed at your eye, it doesn't look like a beam. Instead, whatever is emitting the beam has a very bright spot on it.

Sometimes you can see a beam. If the air is dusty, each dust particle is struck by a lot of light. Each particle scatters light in all directions. Some of it reaches your eye. The beam looks like glowing dust.

The colors you see depend on a number of things.

- The colors (or wavelengths or frequencies) the light source puts into the beam.
- The way the dust or other objects interact with those wavelengths.
- The way your eye responds to the wavelengths that arrive.

Your eye responds to visible wavelengths, but not infrared. So you don't see it even if it enters your eye. Your camera does respond to infrared light. This is why you were able to see a picture of the beam.

If you want glasses that make the beam visible, you should investigate night vision goggles. These are a combination of a camera + viewer, like a cell phone. Plus some lenses so you can put it right in front of your eye and still see it in focus. But it is not a small thing.

---

If you are interested in changing the wavelength to the visible range, you could work with the dust. This is not a promising approach for converting infrared to visible. It would be better for going the other way.

Most materials reflect light. This means they change the direction of the light, but do not change the light itself. They can change the color of the light by only reflecting some of the colors.

Some materials are fluorescent. They do change the light. They absorb light that hits them and give off new light of a different color. But these only give back part of the energy that was in the light. That is, they absorb high energy, short wavelength light and give off low energy, long wavelength light. Infrared has longer wavelengths than visible light.

---

The other approach would be to work with the source. Change it from infrared to visible.

Comment: Here: http://www.bromba.com/indicard/indicare.htm read about IRI4400 cards. They convert infrared to green in a multiphoton process. (But of course not a "beam" or a picture