# How Can I Observe the Refraction of Infrared Waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, electronics, infrared-radiation

It is my plant to propagate infrared and place a certain barrier in front of it. How would I go about observing the behaviour of the waves after passing this barrier?

Comment: I need to know a little more about you setup.

Comment: @john I will place an infrared transmitter somewhere. A metter in front of it will be a square-shaped object. I want to see how the wave diffracts after passing this object.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162739/37364

Answer (score 0):

You could place arrays of ir-detectors behind the barrier to see where and in what direction the ir emerged from barrier. If a wall or other object was placed a few meters behind the barrier, ir detectors could be placed on it in some pattern.  I have no idea on the price of small ir detectors. You'd also have to make sure the detectors were sensitive to your transmitted frequency.  Once an idea of where the ir strike the wall, you can change you pattern of detectors to better map the ir impact region.